# Block coockies from Facebook and Twitter SDK

Tags: facebook, cookies, twitter

I have a very basic HTML page and I just added the option to share it via Twitter or Facebook. However when I added:

```
https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
```

I realized that a few cookies (7 for Facebook & 19 for Twitter) appeared on my page. As looking through the code I saw that the FB.init function has an option to disable cookies:

```
FB.init({
    appId: "122980495023997",
    channelUrl :'http://playthepiano.com',
    status: true,
    xfbml: true,
    cookie: false
});
```

or at least that is what I thought. However, even when I switched it to false I still have cookies from Facebook on my page. For Twitter my searched showed nothing. Is there a way I can completely block all cookies from Facebook and Twitter?

PS: I am very new to developing so please excuse me if my questions makes no sense. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, the cookie parameter does not mean it will set no cookies at all. If you don’t want cookies, then don’t embed those scripts in the first place. Both networks have versions of their share dialogs that can be triggered via URL only (research) - if you use those, there will be no cookies created under your domain. (The drawback is that you won’t get any “share count” or similar shown either.)

Comment: @CBroe, thank you very much. The idea with the URL triggering approach is working perfectly. (For those who want to open it in a popup window use: `window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)`.